# Bounding ellipse constrained to horizontal/vertical axes

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry

Context: I'm trying to clip a topographic map into the minimum-size ellipse around a number of wind turbines, to minimize the size of the map. The program doing this map clipping can clip in ellipses, but only ellipses with axes aligned along the x and y axes.

I know the [algorithm for the bounding ellipse problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768197/bounding-ellipse) (finding the smallest-area ellipse that encloses a set of points).

But how do I constrain this algorithm (or make a different algorithm) such that the resulting ellipse is required to have its major axis oriented either horizontally or vertically, whichever gives the smallest ellipse -- and never at an angle?

[image]

Of course, this constraint makes the resulting ellipse larger than it "needs" to be to enclose all the points, but that's the constraint nonetheless.

Comment: and what about making the algorithm more general: allowing more ellipses and looking for solution with highest information criterion (equivalent to smallest AIC value)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9542) (referenced in the link you provided) is about solving the following optimization problem:

```
minimize log(det(A))
s.t. (P_i - c)'*A*(P_i - c)<= 1
```

One can extend this system of inequalities with the following constraint (V is the ellipse rotation matrix, for detailed info refer the link above):

```
V == [[1, 0], [0, 1]] // horizontal ellipse
```

or

```
V == [[0, -1], [1, 0]] // vertical ellipse
```

Solving the optimization problem with either of these constraints and calculating the square of the resulting ellipses will give you the required result.