# Check if point lies inside mulit-dimensional ellipsoid

Tags: matlab, math, algebra

I have problem with determining if certain points lie inside multi-dimensional ellipsoid.
The real problem is caused by potential transformations (rotations, translations) and I don't know how to apply them to my computations.

In my work I will have set of points for which I need to find minimum volume enclosing ellipsoid. Then I will have to check other set of points and determine which of them belong to the found ellipsoid.

I have decided to use code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016898/port-matlab-bounding-ellipsoid-code-to-python):

```
function [] = Checkup()
points  = [[ 0.53135758, -0.25818091, -0.32382715] 
    [ 0.58368177, -0.3286576,  -0.23854156,] 
    [ 0.18741533,  0.03066228, -0.94294771] 
    [ 0.65685862, -0.09220681, -0.60347573]
    [ 0.63137604, -0.22978685, -0.27479238]
    [ 0.59683195, -0.15111101, -0.40536606]
    [ 0.68646128,  0.0046802,  -0.68407367]
    [ 0.62311759,  0.0101013,  -0.75863324]];
P = points\'; % <- remove the \ symbol here
dimen = length(P(:,1));

% c - vector with ellipse centers
[A, c] = MinVolEllipse(P, 0.01);
[~, Q, V] = svd(A);
radiuses = 1:dimen;

% Calculate radiuses
for i = 1:dimen
    radiuses(1, i) = 1 / sqrt(Q(i,i));
end

% Check if points lie within ellipse and print Ok for every point inside ellipsoid
for i = 1:length(P(1,:)) % length(P(1,:)) is number of points
    value = 0;
    for j = 1:dimen
        %adding ((p_i - c_i) / (r_i))^2 value
        value = value + ( ( (P(j,i) - c(j, 1) )^2 ) / (radiuses(1, j)^2));

    end
    if value <= 1
        disp('Ok')
    end
end
```

Right now this code does not print Ok text (but it should print it 8 times).

According to [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9542-minimum-volume-enclosing-ellipsoid): "V is the rotation matrix that gives you the orientation of the ellipsoid"
I think this is the last element I need to use for my code to work.

### My approach

Ok so I made some changes to my code.
Right now I try to do something like this:

Assuming I have center of ellipsoid and its radius.

For every point:

1. Update position as follows: point = point - center -> in other words translate it as if ellipsoid had it center in point (0, 0, ... 0)
2. Rotate it as if ellipsoid was parallel to all axes: point = invert(V) * point
3. Check if point lies inside ellipsoid using equation: (point.x / radius.x)^2 + ... + (point.i / radius.i)^2 where i is number of dimensions
4. If equation gave result <= 1 then point lies within ellipse.

Is this approach good? I mean - I don't know if I'm allowed to invert V matrix and use it as if it inverted previous rotation...

### Proper solution

Looks like my proposed approach was good but there is one even better:

```
function [result] = Ellipse()
% Returns vector consisting of 10 entries
% that represent error ratio for every test set 

result = 0:9;

% Run tests for all point sets
for pointSet = 0:9
    [Ptraining, Ptest] = LoadPointSet(pointSet);
    count = 0;

    % c - vector with ellipse centers
    [A, c] = MinVolEllipse(Ptraining, 0.00001);

    % Check if points lie within ellipse
    for i = 1:length(Ptest(1,:)) % length(P(1,:)) is number of points
        pp = Ptest(:, i) - c;
        value = pp' * A * pp;    
        if value > 1
            count = count + 1;
        end
    end

    % Get the error ratio
    index = pointSet + 1;
    result(index) = count / length(Ptest(1,:));
end

end
```

Comment: where are the details? what equation you are using? is it axis alligned ellipsoid or not? what is the problem have you been trying to debug? I would use visual check for correctness like do a set of random points 3D  plot and set their color by your predicate function for some test ellipsoid... there you should see what is wrong directly ... also you can add the ellipsoid plot into it to see if your predicate coresponds as it should

Comment: What part of my problem is not clear to you? I try to determine if certain point belongs to the found ellipsoid. In the matlab code I have provided I find minimum volume enclosing ellipsoid for 8 points in 3d space. Visualization can be found in the link provided earlier in the description.

Comment: it is not that the task is not clearly stated ... the problem is that you did not describe how are you solving this and how exactly your current approach is wrong. If you visualize as I proposed you will see what exactly is considered by your predicate as inside ellipsoid hence easier inferring what is wrong ...

Comment: How about now? I updated my approach section.

Comment: There is **NO** reason to close this question. For those of you who don't understand mathematics, go away. You do not need to close questions that those of us who do know mathematics can answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right now this code does not print Ok text (but it should print it 8 times).

First off, there is no reason to expect that an approximate algorithm such as the `MinVolEllipse` function will give the exact minimum volume enclosing ellipse. You are supplying a tolerance to `MinVolEllipse`, so you should expect some error in the result from that function.

More importantly, you don't need to use a singular value decomposition here (but see below for details). The equation for the surface of an ellipsoid is (x-c)<sup>T</sup>A(x-c)=1. All you need to check is whether (x-c)<sup>T</sup>A(x-c) is less than one (plus some tolerance) for each of your points:

```
tol_mvee = 0.01;
tol_dist = 0.1;

[A, c] = MinVolEllipse(P, tol_mvee);

% Check if points lie within ellipse and print Ok for every point inside ellipsoid
for i = 1:length(P(1,:)) % length(P(1,:)) is number of points
    x   = P(i,:);
    x_c = x-c;
    d   = dot(x_c, A*x_c);
    if d < 1+tol_dist
        disp('Ok');
    end
end
```

Your first point is clearly inside the ellipsoid. All of the other seven points are on or very close to the boundary of the true minimum volume enclosing ellipsoid. The algorithm will have a bit of trouble with that, and it will also have a bit of trouble with the fact that the resulting ellipsoid is markedly ellipsoidal rather than spherical (see below on condition number).

A singular value decomposition might be useful to tell you whether the `A` matrix from `MinVolEllipse` is ill-conditioned, which is somewhat the case in this particular problem. The condition number for your matrix is over 200, which means you had better not expect to get a result with a tolerance much smaller than 1e-6.

Comment: Thank you. This is clearly faster than my approach. But would you mind taking look at my way using singular decomposition. Especially the point 2. Is it legal to invert V matrix hoping I'll get matrix that will "revert rotation"?

Comment: Ok I've just checked - both methods return the same results. Thank you!