# Bounding Ellipses using Lat Long, major, minor and Rotation

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have a File that contains an ellipse with lat long, major and minor distance and rotation. Can I use just this information to calculate all the points along the ellipse. The major goal is to take a set of ellipses with these parameters and have ellipse that contains all the other ones. It would be nice if it was a minimum bound, but something close would do.

I think I saw an algorithm on here that allows you to take a set of points and draw a bounding ellipse, so my plan is to use the major and minor lat/long information to get all the points of the set of ellipses and bound it somehow. Is this a good strategy? I don't think it would be minimum since the rotation probably wouldn't be right.

Comment: Your use of “lat long” confuses me. Are you talking about *ellipses on a sphere*? If so, please state that explicitely in your question. Otherwise, *x* and *y* might be less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the surface these ellipses are on is flat (or effectively flat), you can generate a series of points using just that information. There may be a more efficient way, but I've used equations (13) and (14) on [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html) to get the points on an axis-aligned ellipse, then just [rotated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) and offset them by the actual angle and position.

I believe you'll have to iterate towards a bounding ellipse though, the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768197/bounding-ellipse) provides an algorithm. I would generate a number of points for each ellipse dependent on its size (so, more for larger ellipses), then find a [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) to reduce the points you're working with to just the important ones.