# Translating the algorithm of multiplying 2 arrays into Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to multiply 2 arrays in Java. I know how to multiply 2 arrays with each other, but I'm struggling to translate that into Java using 2D arrays (It's my first time using 2D arrays).

I've tried creating a new column variable for the first array, another one for the second one, and another one for the result, but it's not working.

This is what I've written so far

```
public double[][] producto(double[][] m1, double[][] m2){
        double[][] r=new double[m1.length][m1[0].length];
        for(int fila=0, col1 = 0, col=0;fila<m1.length && col1<m1[fila].length;fila++,col1++,col++){
            for(int col2=0; col2<m1[fila].length;col2++){
                r[fila][col]+=m1[fila][col1]*m2[fila][col2];
            }
        }
        return r;
    }
```

When I use `{{1,1,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}}` and `{{2,2,2},{2,2,2},{2,2,2}}` as inputs I get tze actual output `{{6,0,0},{0,6,0},{0,0,6}}` while I would expect it to be `{{6,6,6},{6,6,6},{6,6,6}}`.

Comment: This is solved here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547462/how-to-multiply-2-dimensional-arrays-matrix-multiplication

Comment: Please repeat for me, how does one multiply two matrices? I would have expected three nested loops, not just two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an inner loop :

```
  public double[][] producto(double[][] m1, double[][] m2){
    final int nbRow1 = m1.length;
    final int nbColumn1 = m1[0].length;
    final int nbRow2 = m2.length;
    final int nbColumn2 = m2[0].length;

    if (nbColumn1 != nbRow2) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input");
    }

    double[][] r=new double[nbRow1][nbColumn2];
    for(int row=0;row<nbRow1;row++){
      for(int col=0; col<nbColumn2;col++){
        r[row][col] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nbColumn1; i++) {
          r[row][col]+=m1[row][i]*m2[i][col];
        }
      }
    }
    return r;
  }
```